# Two Passive sentences in one sentence

Tags: sentence, passive-voice

> The bacteria in milk are destroyed when it is heated to 80 degree Celsius.

"The bacteria in milk are destroyed" this is a passive verb in LHS

right?

"when it is heated to 80 degree Celsius."- also passive form.

is not it?

Is both side passive form accaptable?

Comment: The usage of the passive voice is defensible when it is used to describe processes or when an actor is unimportant, especially in technical writing. You would hardly say "You can destroy bacteria in milk by heating it to 80 degree Celsius" in a scientific paper.

Comment: I would prefer '80 degrees celsius'

Comment: It's not "both side passive"; there are no "sides". Instead, the main clause is the first one, and the second clause is subordinate to the main clause. Since Passive is a cyclic rule, it can occur once in any clause that meets its requirements, and both of the clauses there do so. Consequently it's perfectly fine. Where in the world did the idea that only one passive can be used in a sentence come from? It's totally absurd.

Comment: @highvit *"You would hardly say 'You can destroy bacteria in milk by heating it to 80 degree Celsius' in a scientific paper."* Of course you could. Many modern academic institutions let you use *I* now too. The rule isn't universal. The only problem I have with both versions of this sentence is the slightly difficult parsing of *it*. I know that *it* refers to the milk, but there's also a tendency to associate it with the bacteria instead. Of course, heating the bacteria would also be correct. But I'd prefer that it be either *they* (the bacteria) or *the milk*, without a pronoun at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford I also found it a little difficult to parse at first. I'd write something like *If you heat milk to 80 degrees Celsius, the bacteria in it will be destroyed.*